# Why I have the error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, styles

i'm making a form with bootstrap, when I open my HTML file from the folder I have the following error and the styles are not loading [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32QIr.png)

But when I use Live Server in Visual Studio Code to open the HTML there is all Ok[live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzTZr.jpg)

Why is it happen and how can I solve it? here is my code:

```
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/practica bootstrap-copia/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/practica bootstrap-copia/form.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bodoni+Moda:wght@400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Arma tu cv</title>
```

```
<!-- BOOTSTRAP AND JS -->
<script src="/practica bootstrap-copia/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts.js"></script>
```

[my folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyxnt.jpg)

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: This: `/practica bootstrap-copia/css/bootstrap.min.css` contains a space character. Don't use spaces in directory or file names that will be accessed with `href` or `src`. This will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your problem and found the solution.  Remove your leading forward slashes in your hrefs.  They need to be relative directory positions, not absolute.

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="practica bootstrap-copia/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="practica bootstrap-copia/form.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bodoni+Moda:wght@400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Arma tu cv</title>
```